# I want to add a hammingWeight of BitVec to a solver,but something wrong with it

Tags: z3py

I first added constraints to BitVec, and then add hamming weights of these BitVec to a constraint,but the constraint of hamming weight does't work

I put the solution into the constraints, the solution satisfies the constraints of the first part,but don't satisfies the constraint of hamming weight

```py
    from z3 import *

    s=Solver()

    def hammingWeight(x,n):
        return sum(ZeroExt(n,Extract(i,i,x)) for i in range(n))

    rounds=3
    weight=3

    x=[BitVec('x'+str(i),16) for i in range(rounds+1)]
    y=[BitVec('y'+str(i),16) for i in range(rounds+1)]
    z=[BitVec('z'+str(i),16) for i in range(rounds)]
    hw=[BitVec('z'+str(i),16) for i in range(rounds)]

    def round(r,x,y,z,hw):
        varbits=RotateLeft(x[r],8)|RotateLeft(x[r],1)
        doublebits=RotateLeft(x[r],1)&(~(RotateLeft(x[r],8))&RotateLeft(x[r],15))
        y[r+1]=x[r]
        x[r+1]=y[r]^z[r]^RotateLeft(x[r],2)
        hw[r]=varbits^doublebits
        s.add(z[r]&varbits==0,(z[r]^RotateLeft(z[r],7))&doublebits==0)

    for r in range(rounds):
        round(r,x,y,z,hw)
    s.add(hammingWeight(x[0],16)+hammingWeight(y[0],16)!=0)
    hw=0
    for r in range(rounds):
        hw+=hammingWeight(hw[r],16)

    s.add(hw<=weight)
    print(s.check())
    print(s.model())
```

the solution find a model,but the model unsat in the constraint: hw<=weight

Answer (score 0):

When I run your program, I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 29, in <module>
    hw+=hammingWeight(hw[r],16)
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is because you've redefined `hw` from a bit-vector list and later assigned it to `0`. Perhaps a cut-paste error? Please repost after fixing that first.